# Hacer identificación en login con python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando realizar mi propio *web crawler*, y para ello quiero empezar con el logueo en formulario para posteriormente obtener la página que ya se como hacerlo.

En el login estoy teniendo algun fallo y no se de donde viene, a ver si con vuestra experiencia me podeis echar un cable, aquí os dejo el código:

```
 import requests


url = "http://www.forosdelweb.com/usercp.php"

payload = {
    'vb_login_username':'nombre_usuario',
    'vb_login_password':'password_usuario',
    'submit':'Iniciar Sesión'
}

s = requests.Session()

logueo = s.post(url, data=payload)
r = s.post('http://www.forosdelweb.com')

if( (logueo.status_code)  == 200 ):
    print("Peticion de login aceptada")
else:
    print("El login esta fallando")


if ('nombre_usuario' in r.text):
    print("Has realizado el login correctamente")
else:
    print ('Fallo, no te has autenticado correctamente')
```

Comment: Que fallo te imprime? O directamente no sale nada? Has probado esto? (borrar 'data') logueo = s.post(url, payload)

Comment: Me imprime esto:                                                                                   "Peticion de login aceptada
Login Failed" y acabo de probar quitando el data= y me hace lo mismo

Comment: Revisa si requiere cookies o si tiene algun input oculto, es comun para evitar ataques CSRF

Comment: efectivamente el tema viene por las input ocultas para los ataques csrf, pero no tengo ni idea de como saltarlo